# How to use PULL from any repository URL

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Basically you pull from a repository that your clone is made from.
But what if I want to pull from a different repository, as you would do with this command:

```
hg pull REPO_URL
```

How is this done in TortoiseHG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to read hgrc for repo?

In it's [paths] section you can define as many paths to repo as you want by hand,  **or** add additional repos with GUI in Synchronize tool and later use the Synchronize for selecting needed external and pull-push with it